# Get all of the rows involved between tables relationships

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, optimization

I have a SQL Server 2016 with the following tables:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Code] (
    [CodeId]            INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Serial]            VARCHAR(20)  NOT NULL,
    [AggregationLevelId]  TINYINT      NOT NULL,
    [CommissioningFlag] TINYINT        NOT NULL,
    [ ... ]
    CONSTRAINT [PK_CODE] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([CodeId] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [UC_CODE_SERIAL] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED ([Serial] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Code_AggregationLevelConfiguration]
           FOREIGN KEY ([AggregationLevelId])
            REFERENCES [dbo].[AggregationLevelConfiguration] ([AggregationLevelConfigurationId])
)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Aggregation] (
    [AggregationId] INT           NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_AGGREGATIONS] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([AggregationId] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Aggregation_Code]
           FOREIGN KEY ([AggregationId])
            REFERENCES [dbo].[Code] ([CodeId])
)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AggregationChildren] (
    [AggregationChildrenId] INT NOT NULL,
    [AggregationId]         INT NOT NULL,
    [Position]              INT NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_AGGREGATION_CHILDS] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([AggregationChildrenId] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_AggregationChildren_Code]
           FOREIGN KEY ([AggregationChildrenId])
            REFERENCES [dbo].[Code] ([CodeId]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_AggregationChildren_Aggregation]
           FOREIGN KEY ([AggregationId])
            REFERENCES [dbo].[Aggregation] ([AggregationId]) ON DELETE CASCADE
)
```

`Aggregation` and `AggregationChildren` represent relations between rows in table `Code`.

An aggregation will have 1 or more aggregation children. And also, a code in aggregation children could have 0 or more aggregation children.

It is something like this:

```
Code1
|___________________
|                   |
Code2               Code3
|________           |________________
|        |          |        |       |
Code4    Code5      Code6    Code7   Code8
```

All of the above are `Code.Serial` values.

All of the `Code.CodeId` values for those serials are in `Aggregation` table for `Code1`, `Code2` and `Code3`.

And, for those serials, `Code2`, `Code3`, `Code4`, `Code5`, `Code6`, `Code7`, and `Code8` are in `AggregationChildren` table.

I need to update `Code.CommissioningFlag` for all of those serials.

I have created a stored procedure to called recursively. I pass `Code1` as argument, and it will do a recursive call for `Code2` and `Code3`.

This method works fine with a few codes, but now, I have to update 3,000 codes and it blocks SQL Server.

I've thought I have navigate throw the 'tree' and get a temp table with all of the codes, and the do and update for all of them, but I don't know how to 'navigate the tree' in SQL.

How can I get all the codes to update all of them at once?

Comment: Please could you add some sample date and the desired result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your explanation I think you could use a recursive solution. I've set up a minimal example:

> ```
> INSERT INTO dbo.Code VALUES
> (1,  'Code1',  1, 1),
> (2,  'Code2',  2, 1),
> (3,  'Code3',  2, 1),
> (4,  'Code4',  3, 1),
> (5,  'Code5',  3, 1),
> (6,  'Code6',  3, 1),
> (7,  'Code7',  3, 1),
> (8,  'Code8',  3, 1),
> (9,  'Code9',  1, 3),
> (10, 'Code10', 2, 3),
> (11, 'Code11', 2, 3);
> GO
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO dbo.Aggregation VALUES (1),(2),(3),(9);
> GO
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO dbo.AggregationChildren VALUES
> (2,  1, 1),
> (3,  1, 2),
> (4,  2, 1),
> (5,  2, 2),
> (6,  3, 1),
> (7,  3, 2),
> (8,  3, 3),
> (10, 9, 1),
> (11, 9, 2);
> GO
> ```

> ```
> DECLARE @Serial VARCHAR(20) = 'Code1';
>
> SELECT CodeId FROM dbo.Code WHERE Serial = @Serial;
>
> SELECT    AggregationId Id
> FROM      dbo.Aggregation
> WHERE     AggregationId = (SELECT CodeId FROM dbo.Code WHERE Serial = @Serial);
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> | CodeId |
> | -----: |
> |      1 |
>
> | Id |
> | -: |
> |  1 |
> ```

The anchor selects first row from `dbo.Aggregation`, and the recursive query rows from `dbo.AggregationChildren` where `AggregationId` match AggregationId of `dbo.Aggregation`.

Then simply update `Code` table using the list of ID's returned by the recursive query.

> ```
> DECLARE @Serial VARCHAR(20) = 'Code1';
>
> ;WITH rc AS
> (
>     SELECT AggregationId Id
>     FROM   dbo.Aggregation
>     WHERE  AggregationId = (SELECT CodeId FROM dbo.Code WHERE Serial = @Serial)
>     UNION ALL
>     SELECT ac.AggregationChildrenId Id
>     FROM   dbo.AggregationChildren ac
>     JOIN   rc
>     ON     ac.AggregationId = rc.Id
> )
> UPDATE c
> SET    CommissioningFlag = 5
> FROM   dbo.Code c
> JOIN   rc
> ON     c.CodeId = rc.Id;
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> 8 rows affected
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM dbo.Code;
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> CodeId | Serial | AggregationLevelId | CommissioningFlag
> -----: | :----- | :----------------- | :----------------
>      1 | Code1  | 1                  | 5                
>      2 | Code2  | 2                  | 5                
>      3 | Code3  | 2                  | 5                
>      4 | Code4  | 3                  | 5                
>      5 | Code5  | 3                  | 5                
>      6 | Code6  | 3                  | 5                
>      7 | Code7  | 3                  | 5                
>      8 | Code8  | 3                  | 5                
>      9 | Code9  | 1                  | 3                
>     10 | Code10 | 2                  | 3                
>     11 | Code11 | 2                  | 3
> ```

<kbd>*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=5aa298211e4154670843d9931efa3f44)*</kbd>

Comment: It works perfectly. I have updated 3,501 rows in 6 secs. Awesome!!

Comment: I have forgotten that I have to delete also all of those codes from tables `AggregationChildren` and `Aggregation`. I will try to modify your solution to do that. Thanks.

Comment: I'm glad to be able to help.

Comment: I have asked another question about how to delete them, because I have no idea about how to do it: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/205132/get-all-of-the-rows-involved-between-tables-relationships-to-delete-them