# Get all of the rows involved between tables relationships to delete them

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, optimization

Continuing with the question [Get all of the rows involved between tables relationships](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/205030/get-all-of-the-rows-involved-between-tables-relationships), now I have to delete all the rows for those codes. I explain:
I have a SQL Server 2016 with the following tables:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Code] (
    [CodeId]            INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Serial]            VARCHAR(20)  NOT NULL,
    [AggregationLevelId]  TINYINT      NOT NULL,
    [CommissioningFlag] TINYINT        NOT NULL,
    [ ... ]
    CONSTRAINT [PK_CODE] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([CodeId] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [UC_CODE_SERIAL] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED ([Serial] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Code_AggregationLevelConfiguration]
           FOREIGN KEY ([AggregationLevelId])
            REFERENCES [dbo].[AggregationLevelConfiguration] ([AggregationLevelConfigurationId])
)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Aggregation] (
    [AggregationId] INT           NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_AGGREGATIONS] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([AggregationId] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Aggregation_Code]
           FOREIGN KEY ([AggregationId])
            REFERENCES [dbo].[Code] ([CodeId])
)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AggregationChildren] (
    [AggregationChildrenId] INT NOT NULL,
    [AggregationId]         INT NOT NULL,
    [Position]              INT NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_AGGREGATION_CHILDS] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([AggregationChildrenId] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_AggregationChildren_Code]
           FOREIGN KEY ([AggregationChildrenId])
            REFERENCES [dbo].[Code] ([CodeId]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_AggregationChildren_Aggregation]
           FOREIGN KEY ([AggregationId])
            REFERENCES [dbo].[Aggregation] ([AggregationId]) ON DELETE CASCADE
)
```

`Aggregation` and `AggregationChildren` represent relations between rows in table `Code`.

An aggregation will have 1 or more aggregation children. And also, a code in aggregation children could have 0 or more aggregation children.

It is something like this:

```
Code1
|___________________
|                   |
Code2               Code3
|________           |________________
|        |          |        |       |
Code4    Code5      Code6    Code7   Code8
```

All of the above are `Code.Serial` values.

All of the `Code.CodeId` values for those serials are in `Aggregation` table for `Code1`, `Code2` and `Code3`.

And, for those serials, `Code2`, `Code3`, `Code4`, `Code5`, `Code6`, `Code7`, and `Code8` are in `AggregationChildren` table.

I need to delete the rows for those serials from `Aggregation` and `AggregationChildren` tables.

Using the [answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/205038/7820) from the previous question, I have tried to do this:

```
DECLARE @Serial VARCHAR(20) = 'Code1';

;WITH rc AS
(
    SELECT AggregationId Id
    FROM   dbo.Aggregation
    WHERE  AggregationId = (SELECT CodeId FROM dbo.Code WHERE Serial = @Serial)
    UNION ALL
    SELECT ac.AggregationChildrenId Id
    FROM   dbo.AggregationChildren ac
    JOIN   rc
    ON     ac.AggregationId = rc.Id
)
UPDATE c
SET    CommissioningFlag = 130
FROM   dbo.Code c
JOIN   rc
ON     c.CodeId = rc.Id;
GO

Delete ag from dbo.Aggregation ag
inner join rc 
on ag.AggregationId = rc.Id;
```

But I don't know how to use the `DELETE FROM` with the `rc` statement. But I think I only need the `Codes` that are in `Aggregation` and `AggregationChildren`. Maybe I need to modify the `With` statement to get first the rows in `Aggregation` table because I have an `ON DELETE CASCADE` in `AggregationChildren` table.

How can I get all the codes to delete from `Aggregation` table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your table schema where there is a rule `ON DELETE CASCADE` in `FK_AggregationChildren_Aggregation` foreign key, you can delete only affected records of 'Aggregation' table.

Use the same recursive query to fetch rows but adding AggregationID of childrens, then delete distinct AggregationId codes.

```
DECLARE @Serial VARCHAR(20) = 'Code1';

;WITH rc AS
(
    SELECT AggregationId Id, null as Code
    FROM   dbo.Aggregation
    WHERE  AggregationId = (SELECT CodeId FROM dbo.Code WHERE Serial = @Serial)
    UNION ALL
    SELECT ac.AggregationChildrenId Id, AggregationID as Code
    FROM   dbo.AggregationChildren ac
    JOIN   rc
    ON     ac.AggregationId = rc.Id
)
DELETE FROM dbo.Aggregation
WHERE AggregationID IN (SELECT DISTINCT Code FROM rc);
```

This is the result:

> ```
> SELECT * FROM dbo.Aggregation;
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> | AggregationId |
> | ------------: |
> |             9 |
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM dbo.AggregationChildren;
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> AggregationChildrenId | AggregationId | Position
> --------------------: | ------------: | -------:
>                    10 |             9 |        1
>                    11 |             9 |        2
> ```

<kbd>*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=1463dd7216678de84a49289f019947ed)*</kbd>